# Multiple addons using the same name

Tags: add-on, customization, command-line

I was trying to install the add-on Blam Master and for any reason was not showing up, and didn't show any action confirming the installation. I try to run it again an this error popped out:

```
Multiple addons using the same name found!
likely a problem with the script search path.
(see console details)
```

Looking at the console nothing shows up... Also, I tried to search for the duplicate file in the Program Files folder, and the AppData folder, but there is no duplicate add-on either.

How can I get rid of the warning? Is there a statement I need to execute in the console? I'm using Windows 10 i7 processor

Comment: Check the system console https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/console_window.html , not the python console.  The offenders will be in your addons folders.

Comment: I would add @batFINGER link to the answer from cegaton. Very helpful as well.

Comment: I have this same issue "Multiple addons using the same name" on MAC OS X. Don't know where to find the console or the duplicate add ons. Who can help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In windows OS you can open the **[console](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/console_window.html)** form the menu:

Window->Toggle System Console:

[image]

There you should be able to find information on your error.

In your case you have a duplicated addon. This error can happen when you have two versions of the same addon as well.

The duplicate could be in two places:

On the programs folder in your system drive:

- C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\ *version number* \scripts\addons

or on the App data folder:

- C:\Users\ *your user* \AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\ *version number* \scripts\addons

Open both folders, find the duplicate and remove it from the folder.

Then restart blender.

Comment: This works like a charm... I would add to the answer, like in my case, I reopen the application, and nothing was shown in the Terminal, I have to open the User Preferences dialog, then the duplicate files were shown with the error in the Terminal. The funny thing was that the add-on that I thought was causing the error was not the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error at one point, so I will expand on Cegaton's answer with what the solution was for my case as it may be helpful. The duplicate files may also appear in the *addons_contrib* folder.