# Multiple addons with the same name found!

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

How do I fix this problem? I don't even know know which add on is duplicated and how to remove it.

[image]

Comment: It indicates "(see console for details)"... maybe you should have a look at the console (Window menu, then toggle system console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple addons using the same name](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48140/multiple-addons-using-the-same-name) and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64778/multiple-addons-using-the-same-name-os-x

Comment: Am a newbie.  Don't really know how to go about it not to mention am used to the console part of blender

Comment: Just for better readability take your next screenshot using Win+Print. Or some other method you find online